# Why does Laravel 5.8 migration not work without changing the table name?

Tags: mysql, sql, laravel, laravel-5.8

I have the following table schema;

```
Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('email');
            $table->timestamp('email_verified_at')->nullable();
            $table->string('password');
            $table->string('account_type')->default('1,1,0');
            $table->string('theme')->default('light');
            $table->string('unique_id')->nullable();
            $table->string('avatar')->nullable();
            $table->rememberToken();
            $table->timestamps();
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('plan_id');
            $table->foreign('plan_id')->references('id')->on('plans');
            $table->unique('email');
        });
```

When I run migrate, it fails with the error:

> errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed"

If I remove the foreign key, it still doesn't work.

It does work, if I change the table name from 'users' to anything else, but will then fail if I run it again (requiring the table name to be changed again).

Here is the schema for the table that is referenced, this migration also runs before the users migration.

```
Schema::create('plans', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->string('name')->unique();
            $table->float('cost', 8, 2)->nullable();
            $table->integer('free_trial');
            $table->string('renewal_rate');
            $table->string('features');
            $table->string('stripe_plan');
            $table->boolean('featured')->default(true);
            $table->string('permission');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
```

Having spent days trying to resolve this, everyone seems to point to the `bigIncrements`/`unsignedBigIncrements` being the same along with typos in the column names. I don't seem to have that issue..

Comment: so if instead of users you use like "asdasdasd" it works?

Comment: users won't work, it works if I change the table name once, but then it will break again, with the error above. I want the table name to be users.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to be an issue with XAMPP, reinstalling XAMPP has fixed the issue, I'm not sure of the cause, it has also reduced the time taken to migrate from around 5-10 seconds per table to 0.1-0.6 per table.

Answer (score 0):

You want to create `users` table before plans `table`. That is why you are getting this error. Firstly you need to create users table without `'plan_id'`:

```
Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('email');
            $table->timestamp('email_verified_at')->nullable();
            $table->string('password');
            $table->string('account_type')->default('1,1,0');
            $table->string('theme')->default('light');
            $table->string('unique_id')->nullable();
            $table->string('avatar')->nullable();
            $table->rememberToken();
            $table->timestamps();
            $table->unique('email');
        });
```

Then migrate both tables (`users` and `plans`). After migrate, you need to create new migration.

Write on console: `php artisan make:migration add_plan_id_to_users --table=users`

Then add this to your new migration:

```
$table->unsignedBigInteger('plan_id');
$table->foreign('plan_id')->references('id')->on('plans');
```

Comment: I created the users table after plans as plans had the foreign key - is this wrong?

So doing it this way, will I need a separate migration for each foreign constraint?

Comment: If you created `users` table after `plans` no need to separate migration. Note: users table is given first as default in Laravel package

Comment: I have created the users table after plans, this is also a customised users table from the default Laravel package. The strange thing is that it works if I change ```users``` to anything, such as ```users2``` for one migration. But then will break if I have to ```php artisan migrate:fresh```

Comment: To add to this, I have now tried running this with a new database - the users table now passes correctly, but a seemingly random table will fail with ```errno: 13 "Permission denied"``` Despite the correct permissions being in place (and it already creating several tables, before failing).